# how can I sort list items in flutter/dart based on dateTIme and TimeOfDay?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm making a Todo app, so I want to sort list of tasks based on date and time  chosen by user,
currently I'm soring like this, but its not accurate all the time, any other suggestions??

```
class TaskModel { //model of task
final String? id;
final String? title;
final DateTime? date;
final String? field;
final TimeOfDay? time;
bool isFinished;
TaskModel({
@required this.date,
@required this.id,
@required this.title,
@required this.time,
this.field = 'other',
this.isFinished = false,
});
//method right now I'm using to compare(not efficient)
_tasks.sort((a, b) => a.date!.compareTo(b.date!));
_tasks.sort((a, b) => a.time!.hour.compareTo(b.time!.hour));
_tasks.sort((a, b) => a.time!.minute.compareTo(b.time!.minute));
```

Comment: you can use timestamps, MillisecondsSinceEpoch, or MicrosecondsSinceEpoch. first convert the date to one of them and then you can compare them efficiently.  other solution can be using custom compare

Comment: i have to objects 1)Date chosen by user from date picker 2)time chosen by user from a time picker...so i have to consider both of them while soring ...is this way can do that?

Comment: see my answer, I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
YOURLIST.sort((a, b)=> a.microsecondsSinceEpoch.compareTo(b.microsecondsSinceEpoch));
```

---

you can parse DateTime from date and time that users select as follow:

```
DateTime testDate = DateTime.parse("2021-08-01 20:18:04");
print(testDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

so you can replace `2021-08-01 20:18:04` with `selectedDate selectedTime`